# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport": When i try to update cocoapods version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":

```
  In Gemfile:
    cocoapods (~> 1.9.3) was resolved to 1.9.3, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.2, < 5)

    ion_develop_rails (~> 7.4) was resolved to 7.6.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
```

I am getting above error when i try to run bundle update. Earlier to this the cocoapods version was 1.0.1 and i have updated it to 1.9.3 and tried to 'bundle update' and getting this error.

The steps i tried to fix this.

1. I deleted all the cocoapods information in Gemfile.lock and bundle install but did not get any success with that.
2. I also tried to update the rails gem and then bundle update but no luck.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ion_develop_rails` is really causing you a problem I assume. It wants newer activesupport. So maybe you should stick `ion_develop_rails` to version `7.4`, without `~>` ... but I would remove Gemfile.lock completly and then `bundle install and check if that works for you. If you still need old Gemfile.lock for some reason you can copy it to another place to not lose last working stack.

Comment: @sonic You mean to say i should completely remove Gemfile.lock and then fix the ion_develop_rails version to '7.4' and then run the 'bundle install' right?

Comment: First I would just delete it. Then `bundle install` if it won't resolve on its own then I would stick to version `7.4` and again `bundle install`. I only assume it uses previous version of activerecord if it worked with version 1.0.1 of your other gem.

Comment: @sonic I had tried just deleting the Gemfile.lock and 'bundle install'. It was not working so. I will try the other step now and see.

Comment: @sonic Sorry. Both the methods did not work for me.

Comment: So ion_develop_rails 7,4 still uses activesupport 5.0 and up ? You did remove Gemfile.lock again before sticking to version 7,4 ?

Comment: @sonic Yes. It user activesupport 5.0 and up
ion_develop_rails (= 7.4) was resolved to 7.4.0, which depends on activesupport (>= 5.0). I did remove the Gemfile.lock before bundle install.

Comment: So maybe version 1.0.1 didnt even use activesupport...

Comment: It uses activesupport but the version required is activesupport >= 4.0.2. While for the 1.9.3 cocoapods, 'activesupport >= 4.0.2, < 5'. Is the problem because activesupport is being restricted to <5 for 1.9.3 version of cocoapods?

Comment: I think so thats true

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way to overcome the above issue. Instead of adding cocoapods in Gemfile, if i add it in the gemspec as the dependency with what version i want will resolve the issue.
I have added the cocoapods dependency in gemspec like this
spec.add_dependency 'cocoapods', '~> 1.9'

@sonic. Thanks for your inputs.